# Download SSRS report using Url in webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there any way to download ssrs  report in excelformat in webapi using url
http://myrshost/ReportServer?/activeusers&UserStatus=true&rs:Format=Excel.

When iam browsing this url from browser iam able to download but i want to do this from webapi side.

If i request webapi url the file has to be downloaded in browser.
Any help on this.

Comment: request the report in the web api and forward the response body as an attachment which should also trigger the download in browsers

Comment: Thank you Nkosi ,could you please provide any sample code